# is there any open source project for Restlet on GAE available?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, orm, restlet, objectify

I am searching for open source project for Restlet hosted on GAE and trying to figure out the CRUD operation with restlet + objectify. in my current application i have used following,

- Using Restlet for rest full webservice
- Objectify as ORM framwork.
- Hosted on GAE.

I am not much clear for the how to request response with JSON representation in restlet.

so if there is open source project going on google code or github it would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same technologies in a project.  If you're looking for JSON representation examples, the code below may help.  I am using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to handle JSON serialization/deserialization:

```
public Foo() {

    private String name;

    public Foo() {};

    public Foo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toJson() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
}

@Get("json")
public Representation represent() {

    Foo foo = new Foo("bar");
    return new JsonRepresentation(foo.toJson());

}

@Post("json")
public Representation post(Representation entity) {

    JsonRepresentation json = null;

    try {

        json = new JsonRepresentation(entity);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Foo foo = gson.fromJson(json.getText(), Foo.class);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found one

blog engine: http://code.google.com/p/blogress/